# Python3 `__name__ == '__main__': execution paractices & execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, ftp

I have FTP code which I'm testing with `__name__ == '__main__'` method which works in certain condition and fails on other. This is basically doing FTP to a site with user name password and then traverse into a Directory where we need to inlist the files using `ftplib` module. Along with I have kept the exception handling if could not find the Files in the Dir path then come with a error.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP

def FtpMirroList():
  with FTP("ftp.rraka.com") as ftp:
    ftp.login("rar1", "Hf090rFD")
    ftp.cwd("mirror/Nimble/1522_rc/optimize_gather/")
    #ftp.retrlines('LIST')
    try:
      FileList = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
    except ftplib.error_perm as resp:
      if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
        print("No files in this directory")
      else:
        raise

def main():
  for files in FtpMirroList():
    print(files)

#main()
if __name__ == '__main__':
  FtpMirroList()
```

When I execute this without `main()` which I have hashed in the code then it runs fine.

```
$ ./ftplib-example-4.py
total 19535864
-rw-r--r-- 1   rar1       ftpsecure 9963085277 Jan 09 07:09 15.22.s039.20180109-043530_pslv3.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1   rar1       ftpsecure 387     Jan 09 06:02 15.22.s039.20180109-043530_pslv3.tar.gz.README
-rw-rw-r-- 1   rar1       ftpsecure 9963166015 Jan 09 14:08 15.22.s039.20180109-164514_pslv3.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1   rar1       ftpsecure 387     Jan 09 14:11 15.22.s039.20180109-164514_pslv3.tar.gz.README
```

If I will run this code with `main()` then it will produce the Error for `'NoneType' object` as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ftplib-example-4.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "./ftplib-example-4.py", line 19, in main
    for files in FtpMirroList():
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Please advise best practice to use with  `__name__ == '__main__'` method while using with functions and calling `main()`.

> What i see there is no need of the second function... after editing it
>   works as expected

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
    import ftplib
    from ftplib import FTP

    def FtpMirroList():
      with FTP("ftp.rraka.com") as ftp:
        ftp.login("rar1", "Hf090rFD")
        ftp.cwd("mirror/Nimble/1522_rc/optimize_gather/")
        #ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        try:
          FileList = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        except ftplib.error_perm as resp:
          if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
            print("No files in this directory")
          else:
            raise
        for files in FileList:
          print(files)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      FtpMirroList()
```

Comment: `for files in FtpMirroList()` - that's the line ***with the error*** (the exception says exactly what kind of error), so if you don't call it (with `main()`, since it's in the function called "main"..), the error "won't occur". The practice is to identify and fix broken code. (Hint: what does `FtpMirrorList` return?)

Comment: @user2864740 ..So if that to remov ethen how to list the files?

Comment: Start here at https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x/info and https://www.learnpython.org/ - there are several concepts to learn, have a good time!

Comment: @user2864740 .. its working if hash the `main()` i i saw in my code.. i'm already reading over the pyton doc

Comment: When you "hash the main()" it is commenting the line so **the code is not calling the main() function**. And the error **is in the main() function**. Skipping the main function and calling the FtpMirrorList function directly bypasses *that* error. See the links above: Python is doing *exactly* what it has been told to do.

Comment: @user2864740, thats correct an as a newbie that's what makes me to  understand, anyways thnx for ur advise and quick hints

Comment: This is nothing to do with `name == '__main__'`; your `main` function simply has expectations for `FtpMirrorList` that do not get fulfilled.

Comment: @jonrsharpe .. thnx for your inputs

Answer (score 0):

I got it corrected another way using through `return` keyword in the main function `FtpMirroList` and lastly calling it through `if __name__ == '__main__':` and that works as expected.

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
    import ftplib
    from ftplib import FTP

    def FtpMirroList():
      with FTP("ftp.rraka.com") as ftp:
        ftp.login("rar1", "Hf090rFD")
        ftp.cwd("mirror/Nimble/1522_rc/optimize_gather/")
        #ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        try:
          FileList = ftp.retrlines('LIST')
        except ftplib.error_perm as resp:
          if str(resp) == "550 No files found":
            print("No files in this directory")
          else:
            raise
        for files in FileList:
          return files

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      FtpMirroList()
```